# Why does my code result in a compiler error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to understand why my code causes an compiler error. Can someone explain it to me?

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] JavaLatte) {
        Employee e = new Employee("JavaDeveloper");
        System.out.println("Emp Name : " + e.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking about build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* error output (preferably the full build output) in the question itself. And add a comment in the code you show to tell us which lines the errors are on. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Compiler errors usually tell you theirselves what the problem is. Have you read the error message/stacktrace?

Comment: The compiler error *should* give you some clue as to what the problem is and on which line.  Please post the full error and ideally mark the posted code with the offending line.  That said the problem is `e.name` cannot be accessed in the print statement.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't said what is the error, but I think I see it.

`System.out.println("Emp Name : " + e.name);` - `name` property of `e` is `private`.

That means you can't access it directly from within another class. You need to use a getter.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName(){ return name; }

}
```

And access like this: `e.getName();`

Also to change the value of property you need setters.

```
public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
```

Comment: "That mean you can't access it directly. " -> That means you can't access it directly from within another class.

Comment: @Stultuske My bad. I thought it is clear.

Comment: it was clear, just incomplete. In this context, it's correct, in another, the answer might be wrong. It's easier for the next one to find out why if it's mentioned

Comment: You are right and thanks for completion.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues:

1. You can’t have 2 public classes in the same file.
2. name is a private field. You can’t access it from main. Make a getter for it to access it.

Comment: that is right if u have the code in single class remove Public from Test class.
You need a setter but compilation error is coming  cause the name field is private and cannot be access in other classes

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile as you specified the access specifier as private.

You have many options here

Option 1: Use respective access specifiers like public/protected/default based on your requirement.

option 2 :  Generated public getter & setter  methods for that variable to access variable name.